# While fetching a record in asp.net from sql server it always return null

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

While fetching a record in asp.net from sql server it always return null..here's code-
Even if record is available in database, object oid will have null at run time.
Please help.
thanks.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBMS"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select id from reg where user=@user and password=@pass", con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txUName.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txPass.Text);
    con.Open();
    var oid = com.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();

    if (oid == null)
    {
        lblEr.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Add("id", oid.ToString());
        Session.Add("user", txUName.Text);

        com = new SqlCommand("select type from dbo.reg where user=@u", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", txUName.Text);
        con.Open();
        var otype = com.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();

        var vtype = "admin";
        if (vtype == otype.ToString())
        {
            Session.Add("admin", otype.ToString());
            Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
        }
        Response.Redirect("user.aspx");

    }
}
```

Comment: To debug this you should do 2 steps. First break (or write to debug) the values of txUname.Text and txPass.Text when you add them to the parameters. Are they null or empty?  If those are as expected, then try running that query manually and seeing if it returns the expected result. Also, you should set the SQL CommandType set to text.

Comment: no they are not null or empty.

Comment: It worked just by correcting following syntax-

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select id from reg where [user]=@user and [password]=@pass", con);

Since 'user' is also name of a user in sql server, so when we want to use it at another place like here as column then we have to use it as [user].

Comment: Not really related to your question, but there is very little (if anything) to be gained by reusing your SqlCommand and Connection objects. You would be better off using two objects and placing them in `using` blocks to ensure they are disposed of correctly. You also might want to consider not storing your passwords as plain text!

Comment: Glad you got your problem fixed @user2904107, btw you should consider posting it as a proper answer to your problem so that others can easily find the solution. (You are allowed to accept your own answers.)

Answer (score 0):

It worked just by correcting following syntax-

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select id from reg where [user]=@user and [password]=@pass", con);
```

Since 'user' is also name of a user in sql server, so when we want to use it at another place like here as column then we have to use it as [user].